# VisualSVN Server , Windows 7 and Apache Problem

Tags: apache-2.2, visualsvn-server, svn

I am running Visual SVN Server(with Apache) on a Windows 7 computer and network. After about 15-20 minutes of my first commit/update, I am unable to access the repository via Tortoise SVN.

The error message I get is:
OPTIONS of "https://jason/svn/repository1": could not connect to server (https://jason)

Restarting the Visual SVN Server service helps sometimes but fails quite often. The only sure-shot way to get it working is to restart the computer. The server - https://jason is also not accessible via the browser when I get this error

1) I tried reinstalling Windows 7, Visual SVN server and Tortoise SVN but I still keep getting this error.

2) I searched several forums but I dont seem to be able to find an answer.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up VisualSVN to use port 8443.

Sometimes when you are using two web servers on the same machine there are port conflict.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed VisualSVN on the default port (80) you'll be running into conflicts with Windows 7's built-in services that grab that port for themselves. The easy answer is to use a different port.

The more difficult answer, but possibly the better one, is to disable http.sys, which is a web-services thing Microsoft kindly bundled into the kernel to let .NET WCF apps run a bit easier. (like thanks, MS!)

To disable it:
edit the value `Start` in this key, and set it to 0. reboot.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
```